# Powershell remoting does not work as expected

Tags: powershell, remoting, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I've written a script to push .EXE over to multiple remote servers across domains and install them. When I execute the script, it attempts to run the installer on my local machine. Any review and correction to my script would be of great help. Thank you

```
$uname='domain\username'
$pwd='Password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText
try {
$targets = Get-Content -Path D:\scripts\serverlist.txt
$source = C:\Downloads\installer.exe
$creds=New-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($uname, $pwd)
[ScriptBlock] $code = {
    if(!(Test-Path "C:\Temp"))
    {
        New-Item -Path "C:\Temp" -ItemType Directory
    }
}
    function Installer([string] $file, [String] $argslist)
    {
        $ErrorActionPreference="Stop"
        try
        {
            $exec = Start-Process -FilePath $file -ArgumentList $argslist -Wait -PassThru
            Write-Host "Exit code for installation of $file is $($exec.ExitCode)"
            return $exec.ExitCode
        }
        catch
        {
            throw
        }
    }
foreach($target in $targets){
    $name = GC env:computername
    $current = New-PSSession -ComputerName $name -Credential $creds -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Invoke-Command -Session $current -ScriptBlock $code
    Robocopy $source E:\Temp
    Installer "\\$name\$source" "/q /norestart"
    $current | Remove-PSSession
} }
catch
{
Write-Host -f red "An error has occurred!"
Write-Host "$($error[0].exception)"
$error.clear()
exit $LASTEXITCODE
}
```

Comment: Start-Process will always run on the local machine. You might want Invoke-Command

Comment: Thanks Sami. But the function gets called from within the remote server. So Start-Process would trigger it locally wouldn't it? But nevertheless, I tried replacing it with Invoke-Command but still doesn't work. I get below error:

Comment: You create a session, but you don't enter it or call the function there, so it's called locally

Comment: System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The a
rgument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again. ---> System.Management.Automation.ValidationMetad
ataException: The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again.

Comment: Got it, Sami. But the error is still consistent. It doesn't even seem to get there. It complains that the session is null.

Answer (score 1):

This looks over complicated. I'm not sure what access limitations your environment has, but I would try going this way:

```
$source = Get-Item -Path "C:\Downloads\installer.exe"

ForEach ($target In $targets) {
   Try {
      Copy-Item -Path ($source.FullName) -Destination "\\$target\c$\temp\" -Recurse -Force
      Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName $target -Class Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "C:\temp\$($source.Name) /q /norestart"
   } Catch {
      $_
   }
}
```

Instead of hard coding a username/password, run the script with correct credentials from the start.

`Copy-Item` should create the temp folder automatically, provided the username/password has access to do this.

`Invoke-WmiMethod` will start the process on $target, again provided username/password has access to do this. `Invoke-Command` also works (as Sami mentioned).

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, there's a complete lockdown between those domains with no trust enabled. I tried to circumvent by using the service account that has been whitelisted on the target domain. Your script does help. I tried to use Invoke-WMIMethod and below is the output I get: __GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 2
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
ProcessId        : 1040
ReturnValue      : 0

Comment: I tried multiple ways of Invoke-WMIMethod or Invoke-Command but it either throws the above output or simply ignores the line. Eventvwr doesnt log anything either. Is there a reason why it would not execute the exe? I can do PSEXEC but I'd like to stick to native PowerShell approach. Any advise would be of great help.

Comment: Return value `0` means no errors encountered. On the remote machine, can you see the file was copied, or the process was started? Maybe try notepad.exe while your testing.

Comment: Yes, the file gets copied. Because of a group policy, it prevents you to do a copyover so I had to do dynamic mapping. it goes like this:          ` If (!(Test-Path K:))
 {
  $map = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network
  $map.MapNetworkDrive("K:", "\\ipaddr\temp\software", $true, "domain\user", "password") 
 } ` the installer gets copied. But Invoke-Command doesn't run for some reason.

Comment: On `Invoke-WmiMethod`, try adding the parameter `-Credential (Get-Credential)`